# XCode Admob build failed issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

I was trying to get build my Unity game with XCode. About two weeks ago everything is fine builds are working, but now I have this issue;

- Unity Version: 2021.3.1f1
- Xcode Version: 13.3
- Admob SDK Version: 7.0.0 , 6.1.2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the solution after 2 days;

Use Admob SDK Version: 7.0.0

Build your Project. Go to your project file using terminal. Write this code;

**arch -x86_64 pod install**

Enter

**chmod +x MapFileParser.sh**

Enter

**chmod +x process_symbols.sh**

Then you're ready.

Tried on Unity 2020.3.25 and Unity 2021.3.1f1

**PS: You dont need to write "chmod +x MapFileParser.sh" for 2021.3.1f1**

Comment: Not in a million years I would have figured that out! I wonder how did you do that? Should Unity provide a documentation for this or Google should or Apple should? I'm having issues one after another and so far, I'm still not able to publish my game. Currently I'm having some of the issues OP has mentioned. I'll try this solution today. Thanks in advance sir! Even if it doesn't work, I'm still grateful for your help.